# How to check the server whether it is blocking POST request?

Tags: apache, http, post

How to check whether my server is blocking the post request or not?

Currently in my wordpress, whenever I click update page there will be "The specified URL cannot be found" error. This is not permalink issue. The issue is with server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the error message you say you're getting then POST is enabled and working. The problem is, like the message says, the URL.

Wordpress has this feature to enable "pretty URLs". It could be you've enabled it (or it may come enabled by default, I'm not sure) but don't have the required Apache module - mod_rewrite - enabled.

If you've got access to the command line of the server and your server is on Linux, simply issue:

```
// Enable mod_rewrite
> sudo a2enmod rewrite
// Restart Apache
> sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you would like some more help, please post the URL Wordpress is trying to reach and your Apache configuration to start with.

P.S.
If your server is on Windows, then enabling mod_rewrite depends on which software you've got installed.

Comment: Give me the following: Server operating system, Apache version, PHP version, Wordpress version, Wordpress URL, URL it tries to POST to, what level access have you got for this server. After that, I might also need the contents of some config files.

Comment: Server Version: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Wordpress : 3.8.3
PHP : 5.3.3
WP URL : biomed.unisel.edu.my

When I edit the page, it goes to this URL:
http://biomed.unisel.edu.my/wp-admin/post.php?post=1640&action=edit

Then, when I click Update, it goes to this URL:
http://biomed.unisel.edu.my/wp-admin/post.php

and display
The specified URL cannot be found.

Comment: Well, that's going to make things difficult. Can you at least see httpd.conf or can you print phpinfo(); anywhere?

Comment: I have the phpinfo(), i used some plugin to retrieve them...
This is the screenshot:
http://thiruttudvd.net/wp.htm

Comment: Can you give me a full URL of a blog post?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that the screenshot you've provided indicates PHP is running on your server in FastCGI mode which by its nature cannot use .htaccess files (the special files Wordpress uses for pretty URLs). If I were you, I'd disable pretty URLs to check if this is indeed the issue. From http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks : In the Settings → Permalinks panel, choose 'Default'.

Comment: I did choose default in the permalinks and tried to update the page. It didnt work.

Comment: http://biomed.unisel.edu.my/announcements/new-academic-lecturer/  --- this is full URL of a blog post and it is working fine... this is not an issue with permalink, something to do with the server configuration because the wordpress works fine in my development server but in live server it is not working

Comment: I'm sorry my friend. I don't think I can be of very much help to you unless I get access to your system. If you'd like, we can arrange a screen-share session to solve your issue. **DISCLAIMER**: This is probably **against** StackOverflow's **rules**. Although, I will of course **not** charge any fee or ask for any favours in return.